# Is digitization of discrete valued signal necessary for it to be processed?

Tags: dsp-core

While reading the book DSP by Proakis and Manolakis i came across the concept of digitization of signals. The Author states that Digitization(rounding  it off to nearest integer) of signal is necessary in order for it to be processed by computer. If i write the following code :-

```
float signal[5]={ 1.5 , 1 , 4.4 , 3 , 2 , 3 };
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    signal[i]*=2;
}
```

However, In this above code I am able to process the signal without rounding it off to the nearest integer. Please help me clear my doubt.

Comment: Take a look at the result and check whether it is what you would expect. Your code will indeed round if you use int data type. It would even round for float and double, although it would be less obvious

Comment: I didn't intended to use int data type.

Comment: Even a `float` value is a discrete quantity, since it has finite precision. So it doesn't really matter whether you use `int` or `float` for your samples, they are still quantised (unlike analogue signals).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 1.5 and 4.4 are scaled integers (scaled to the nearest 10th).  C float variables are also a form of scaled integer (exponent indicating the scale factor).  So your data is still rounded to the nearest of smaller scaled integers.

In binary digital computers everything gets converted and broken down into 1-bit integers (or sets of them) before processing by digital logic gates.

Analog computers work differently.